# Unable to set List property of the ListBox class

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that will open a source workbook and then from specific columns it will take only the distinct values and use them to populate ListBoxes that I later use for filtering. The code worked for two ListBoxes but now I had to extend to a third ListBo. I used the same code but now I get the error mentioned above which I don't understand -> I am still very new to VBA

This is the line where it breaks "macroSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 5").List = .keys". The middle block "populate listbox5" is a copy paste from listbox6. If I take out this middle block, the code will run normally.

I noticed is that the data in column F which I use for ListBox 5 is not contiguous -> I have empty cells in between and I assume the code breaks down there. Any hints how to go around it? Filtering out those cells does not seem to work -> I tried with an (If Not eCell = "<>") or even filtering manually.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Temp As Variant
Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
Dim srcBook As Workbook
Dim cCell As Range
Dim lbx As ListBox
Dim macroSheet As Worksheet:      Set macroSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO")
Dim setSheet As Worksheet:        Set setSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts")

Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dict3 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Populate ListBox6
macroSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 6").RemoveAllItems
With dict1
    For Each cCell In srcSheet.Range("G2", srcSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "G").End(xlUp))
        If Not .exists(cCell.Value) Then
            .Add cCell.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next cCell
macroSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 6").List = .keys
End With
'Sort ListBox alphabetically
With macroSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 6")
    For i = 1 To .ListCount - 1
        For j = i + 1 To .ListCount
            If .List(i) > .List(j) Then
                Temp = .List(j)
                .List(j) = .List(i)
                .List(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With

'Populate ListBox5
macroSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 5").RemoveAllItems
With dict2
    For Each cCell In srcSheet.Range("F2", srcSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp))
        If Not .exists(cCell.Value) Then
            .Add cCell.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next cCell
macroSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 5").List = .keys
End With
'Sort ListBox alphabetically
With macroSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 5")
    For i = 1 To .ListCount - 1
        For j = i + 1 To .ListCount
            If .List(i) > .List(j) Then
                Temp = .List(j)
                .List(j) = .List(i)
                .List(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With

'Populate ListBox10
macroSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 10").RemoveAllItems
With dict3
    For Each cCell In srcSheet.Range("L2", srcSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "L").End(xlUp))
        If Not .exists(cCell.Value) Then
            .Add cCell.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next cCell
macroSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 10").List = .keys
End With

'De-Select all Items in all ListBoxes
For Each lbx In macroSheet.ListBoxes
    For i = 1 To lbx.ListCount
        lbx.Selected(i) = False
    Next i
Next lbx
```

Comment: Does the listbox have an input range set?

Comment: no, and it is set to Selection Type "Multi"

Comment: Try excluding the blanks using something like `If Len(cell.value) <> 0 then`

Comment: Thx a lot Rory. That did the trick.